# CSV upload not leaving header, show empty rows if any,match with mysql to prevent duplicate

Tags: php, csv, upload

I need to solve the following problems:

1. My script not leaving headers of CSV file.
2. Show error if empty field in CSV file.
3. Match with MySQL table to prevent duplicate.

---

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            //It wiil insert a row to our subject table from our csv file`
            $sql = "INSERT into old_plot_details (`mem_ship_no`, `mem_fname`, `venture_name`, `phase_name`,`plot_no`, `regd_name`, `doc_no`, `reg_date`)
                    values('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]')";

            //we are using mysql_query function. it returns a resource on true else False on error
            $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            if(!$result)
            {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                    window.location = \"index.php\"
                </script>";
            }
        }
        fclose($file);

        //throws a message if data successfully imported to mysql database from excel file
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
            window.location = \"index.php\"
        </script>";

        //close of connection
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.